# how to access an element of the get_context_data in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to access to the elements of the get_context_data like:

```
context = super(DetallePlanillasContratado,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

and then access in this way:

```
context['new_context'] = context.element_of_the_context
```

do we have something like this on django?

Answer (score 1):

`context['new_context'] = context['elements_of_the_context']`